# Align fields in columns when they have some annotations

Tags: intellij-idea

Try to figure out how to align fields in columns if they have annotations.
Without annotations it works good.

I want to achieve the following view when execute code reformat:

```
    @Null
    private UUID   id;

    @NotNull
    private UUID   otherId;

    @NotNull(groups = ...)
    private String title;
```

But code reformat with enabled 'Group declarations -> Align fields in columns' when we use fields with annotations it seems cannot determine such a group declaration and as a result receive the following view:

```
    @Null
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    private UUID otherId;

    @NotNull(groups = ...)
    private String title;
```

Someone know how to solve it?

Comment: Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149282.

Comment: Thanks for link. It seems it will be fixed - never=)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in the IntelliJ formatter to achieve this but the Eclipse Code Formatter plugin gets the job done.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter